# mono path for F# installation

Tags: f#, mono

I have mono and f# installed and running under linux but wanted to move the directory
of the f# installation. The problem is that, when run with mono, the f# compiler still refers to the old directory. Hence it does not find any dlls and when compiling anything, gives an error like

```
 error FS0078: Unable to find the file 'FSharp.Core.dll' in any of     
 /usr/lib/mono/2.0   
 /current/directory   
 /old/path/of/FSharp-2.0.0.0/bin
```

Since I start the compiler with everything referring to the new path I think mono still refers to the old installation path at some point, but I could not find where. Adding the new path to the MONO_PATH env and updateing the FSHARP_COMPILER_BIN evn to the new path also did not help.
Is there an easy way to change the F# path so the compiler finds it again?

Comment: Which version of F# did you install? Do you want to install `FSharp.Core.dll` to the GAC?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try rerunning the install-mono.sh script? - that should reinstall everything to the GAC with the new location.

Comment: Yes I've tried rerunning the script and it didn't help, so apparently gacutil -i does not overwrite old installations. But one can just use gacutil -u to uninstall the FSharp.Core.dll and then run the script again and it works fine. I'm not sure how I missed that in first place.

Comment: I just checked through the mono sources and it looks like `gacutil -i`will not actually remove the old assemblies - perhaps this should be considered a bug in gacutil?